# How to return a value to a val using if statement?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to convert a var assignment to a val assignment. Currently my code is

```
  // Numerical vectorizing for normalization
  var normNumericalColNameArray: Array[String] = Array()
  if (!continousPredictors.sameElements(Array(""))) {
    if (paramStandardize) {
      println("Apply standardization")
      stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
      stages += new StandardScaler()
        .setWithMean(true)
        .setWithStd(true)
        .setInputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
        .setOutputCol(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
      normNumericalColNameArray = Array(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
    } else {
      println("Not apply standardization")
      stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
      normNumericalColNameArray = Array(NumericalFeaturesCol)
    }
  }

  stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(normNumericalColNameArray ++ oneHotCatColNamesArray).setOutputCol(FeaturesCol)
```

and I want to do something like this

```
  
  val normNumericalColNameArray =
    if (continousPredictors.nonEmpty && paramStandardize) {
    println("Apply standardization")
    stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
    stages += new StandardScaler()
      .setWithMean(true)
      .setWithStd(true)
      .setInputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
      .setOutputCol(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
    Array(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
    } else if (continousPredictors.nonEmpty){
    println("Not apply standardization")
    stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
    Array(NumericalFeaturesCol)
    }


  stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(normNumericalColNameArray ++ oneHotCatColNamesArray).setOutputCol(FeaturesCol)
```

and I run into this error

```
value ++ is not a member of Any
stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(normNumericalColNameArray ++ oneHotCatColNamesArray).setOutputCol(FeaturesCol)
```

I am trying to return the Array from the if condition into my Val normNumericalColNameArray. Can somebody please help?

Comment: `if` is an expression in Scala. it must always result in a value. So you must include a default  `else` branch for the case where no `else if` branch is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is an `if` without an `else` block, so the result could be nothing (`Unit`). Just add an `else` clause:

```
} else if (continousPredictors.nonEmpty) {
  println("Not apply standardization")
  stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)

  Array(NumericalFeaturesCol)
} else {
  Array()
}
```

But `Array` is a Java type, so prefer to use `Vector` or `List` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For an `if` expression, the resulting type is the least-upper-bound of the branches.  If there's no final `else`, there's an implicit

```scala
else ()  // where () is the singleton value of the Unit type
```

So in your `if {} else if` without a final `else`, the overall expression will have the type of whatever the least-upper-bound of `Array[String]`, `Array[String]`, and `Unit` is, which is `Any`, which then becomes the type inferred for `normNumericalColNameArray`.

As Tim and gifa note, you can fix this by adding a final `else` clause.  There's also no need to hoist the inner `if` into the outer condition check:

```scala
val normNumericalColNameArray =
  if (continousPredictors.nonEmpty) {
    stages += new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(continousPredictors).setOutputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)

    if (paramStandardize) {
      println("Apply standardization")
      stages += new StandardScaler()
        .setWithMean(true)
        .setWithStd(true)
        .setInputCol(NumericalFeaturesCol)
        .setOutputCol(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
      Array(StandardizedNumericalFeaturesCol)
    } else {
      println("Not apply standardization")
      Array(NumericalFeaturesCol)
    }
  } else {
    Array[String]()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the if statement. You have:

```scala
val normNumericalColNameArray = {
  if (condition1){
   Array[String]()
  }
  else if (condition2){
   Array[String]()
  }
}
```

Now, your variable has type Any because if *condition1* is not true and *condition2* is not true, then your if statement (function) doesn't return anything: you actually made a partial function. Try adding a final else statement, like:

```scala
val normNumericalColNameArray = {
  if (condition1){
   Array[String]()
  }
  else if (condition2){
   Array[String]()
  }
  else{
   Array[String]()
  }
}
```

It will work then. Also, I would recommend to make your `normNumericalColNameArray` a **lazy val**, so to be evaluated only when it is required, since you are modifying `stages` in the if statement.

Comment: Don't use `return` unless you know what it does. Just make the result the last expression in the block.

Comment: That's right, I was working in another language in parallel and it came out - my bad! I will update the snippet. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys! I am able to fix the issue.